# AX SSRS use expression from another dataset in total

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, ssrs-2012, dynamics-365-operations

I have a header section which is showing totals etc.  I have two fields in another dataset (dataset estimates) which I want to pull into header dataset.

Fee (circled) = IIf(Right(Fields!ProjCategoryId.Value, 3) <> "EXP", Fields!Value.Value, 0)
[image]
3rd Party (circled) = IIf(Right(Fields!ProjCategoryId.Value, 3) = "EXP", Fields!Value.Value, 0)

I know you can sum datasets from another dataset with no issues, but how to use IIF etc. as well?

Comment: Make an invisible textbox and put the value in it, then call that textbox. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53127/ssrs-2008-how-to-total-values-from-an-expression

Comment: I don't think that will work... I believe I still have to use First(Field.Value) rather than it evaluating categoryid's for every line which i want.

Comment: This works! You do not need custom code.  if you provide as answer I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Just mark yours as the answer for others. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually really simple.  Find the Textbox name that contains the expression.  [image]

(When we say textbox this does not have to be a textbox from the toolbox, it can be a field within tablix).  Where you want to reference the value simply add the expression and you can reference the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom code and a `lookupset()`.

Code:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
    If items Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
    Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()

    suma = 0
    ct = 0

    For Each item As Object In items
        suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
        ct += 1
    Next

    If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

- To add this, right-click on the blue background of the report and select **Report Properties**.
- Click on the **Code** option.
  [image: Report Properties Window]
- Paste it into this window
- Call this with `=Code.SumLookup(lookupset("EXP", right(Fields!ProjCategoryId.Value, 3), Fields!Value.Value, "DatasetName"))` in your expression where you want the number to appear

This will add up all the Values where the ProjCategoryId starts with "EXP".

For <> "EXP", you might need to do several calls to it to add them all up for each thing that it can start with. For example..

`Code.SumLookup(lookupset("ONE", right(Fields!ProjCategoryId.Value, 3), Fields!Value.Value, "DatasetName")) + Code.SumLookup(lookupset("TWO", right(Fields!ProjCategoryId.Value, 3), Fields!Value.Value, "DatasetName"))`

Comment: is there no better way of doing this?  why is it so difficult to reference values from another dataset...

Comment: You can just use a `lookup()` if it's a single value you want. `Code.SumLookup(lookupset())` is for aggregating a set of values from another dataset.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help... i'm not too familiar with adding custom code.  Could you edit your post to give me a step by step? It would be much appreciated. Also after I add the code how do i reference the values i've looked up in my dataset....

Comment: @jhowe Edited. Let me know if you face any issues following the steps.